# Drying Oregano and Mint

Tags: indoors, watering, herbs, damage, dryness

I went for a vacation of 4 days and when I came back I found my Oregano drooping. 
Before going I watered it very, but, still it didn't work.

Same happened with my mint as well.

Both the plants are not dying.

How can I save them?

Some of the oregano branches looks like they are broken. Should I trim them? I already watered both the plants. Looks like they are doing well till now.

Should I cover them in plastic and put in shade ?

Anyone any help ?

Here is the photo [image]

Comment: A photo could help.

Comment: How's the humidity? Been a brutal winter for drying leaves here. A water spritzer, or boiling a pot of water may be just the thing.

Answer (score 2):

Do not water them too much. They are plant of dry places. They like also sun, but I would not cover them with plastic.

Now just wait some more time. They are perennials, so they should be able to cope with some weeks of distress. Oregano is also a slow plant, so let it to have time to recover. Mint is nearly a weed, you will not get rid of it so easily.

Comment: Added a photo. Could you please have a look ?

Comment: We are nearing spring equinox, when day length changes fastest, along with fall equinox. Many plants respond to these changes. Yours may just be gearing up for Spring.